# postgresql permission denied to foreign table pg_redis_fdw

Tags: postgresql, redis

I am working with `pg_rdeis_fdw` from postgres.

When I try to insert a record to the existing schema from the `postgres` account, it all works fine.

However, when I try to do the same from another user, I get "permission denied for relation", though i gave the user the following privileges:

```
grant all on FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER redis_fdw to ami;
grant all on FOREIGN SERVER redis_server to ami;
grant all on ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to ami;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE user_redis_hash to ami;
```

The definition is as following (and as I was saying, works just fine from user `postgres`):

```
CREATE EXTENSION redis_fdw;

CREATE SERVER redis_server
   FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER redis_fdw
   OPTIONS (address '127.0.0.1', port '6379');   

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR PUBLIC
            SERVER redis_server
            OPTIONS (password 'secret');

create foreign table user_redis_hash(key text, val text[])
   server redis_server
   options (database '0', tabletype 'hash', tablekeyset 'user:');
```

thanks,
Ami

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to change the owner of the foreign table to the right role. So you might try something like this (from the `postgres` account):

```
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE public.user_redis_hash OWNER TO ami;
```

If you have other foreign tables (as I did) and need to change them all, the following SQL will produce a series of SQL lines you can copy into `psql` prompt to update each foreign table.

```
 SELECT 'ALTER FOREIGN TABLE '|| foreign_table_schema || '.' || foreign_table_name ||' OWNER TO ami;' FROM information_schema.foreign_tables WHERE NOT foreign_table_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') ORDER BY foreign_table_schema, foreign_table_name;
```

If you have other foreign tables for other servers or data wrappers that you do *not* want to change ownership on you can limit the above by adding `AND foreign_server_name = 'redis_server'` to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

To assign access rights to foreign tables to a common user:

```
-- before, we created a foreign server, create user mapping, and made an import foreign schema for the superuser
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER foreign_server TO common_user;
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR common_user SERVER foreign_server OPTIONS (user 'common_user', password 'common_password', password_required 'false');    
grant usage on schema foreign_table_schema to common_user;
grant all on all tables in schema foreign_table_schema to common_user;
```